Horizontal scrollable calendar view for android 13
I want to create horizontally scrollable calendar view like below image.
minSDK = 30
targetSdk  = 34
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
co.bito.bito-intellij (1.3.3)
com.github.copilot (1.5.6.5692)
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7061
Horizontal Calender View is android library.
This library is outdated or simply doesn't work with my version of Android Studio.
